# Google analytics real time not showing source/returning visitors

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics real time doesn't seem to be working properly on a newish domain. Tracking code has been verified and we can see visitors in both real time and audience overview - but all visitors in real time are showing as new, and there is no data in top referrals, top social traffic and top keywords. You can see this data in the audience overview.

Any ideas what is going wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using the new universal analytics profile, which at best should still be considered beta.

It doesn't support everything yet, and there are some odd problems with data collection from time to time.

If you need this to work, you should switch to a classic profile, or at least for now, run both side by side.

Comment: Thanks - hadn't realised I'd chosen the beta one. That explains it!